# extract mean value of raster with buffer condition on second layer/attribute

Tags: r, buffer, raster, spatial, r-stars

[image]
[image]

I have this stars object (could be also formatted to raster):

```
stars object with 2 dimensions and 2 attributes
attribute(s):
   LST_mean        elevation    
 Min.   :14.98   Min.   :296.0  
 1st Qu.:16.89   1st Qu.:346.9  
 Median :17.64   Median :389.3  
 Mean   :17.52   Mean   :389.2  
 3rd Qu.:18.18   3rd Qu.:428.3  
 Max.   :20.11   Max.   :521.6  
dimension(s):
  from to  offset    delta                       refsys point values    
x   71 83 4387654  860.241 DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kru... FALSE   NULL [x]
y   33 41 5598885 -860.241 DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kru... FALSE   NULL [y]
```

Which has 2 attributes (layers in the case of raster): temperature and elevation.
Using temperature, I would like to select the pixels that fall within a buffer and return the mean, only for the pixels whose difference in elevation with the considered one everytime is less than 90 meters.

Any ideas how to do this?
Calculating the averages of the pixels that fall within the buffer is very easy, but I couldn't find a way to set any condition on them.

I will be immensly grateful for your help and suggestions. Approaches using other packages than `satrs` are also very welcome :)

Comment: Hi, sounds like an interesting question! Not sure if I understand "select the pixels that fall within a buffer and return the mean, only for the pixels whose difference in elevation with the considered one everytime is less than 90 meters" - could you please clarify what is the "considered one"? Do you mean to create a (circular?) buffer around a particular pixel, then take the mean from a subset of those pixels which are within the buffer, based on difference in elevation?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I mean.
I am trying with this function on one pixel:
`temp_mean <- function(x,...){
buff_mean <- ifelse(abs(x[[2]][1] - x[[2]]) > 90,NA,x[[1]])
mean(buff_mean,na.rm=T)
}`
and then use it on the pixels selected with the buffer:
`temp_mean(subset[st_buffer(subset2_sf,2000)])`
But I can't generalize it on the raster. and I don't want to use a loop because then it will take forever with the whole rasters.

Comment: I understand, thanks! The loop approach you suggest is a good choice if the raster is not too big, so it is really a matter of data size and memory limits. This "loop" approach can be improved by (1) calculating all buffer polygons in advance, outside of the loop, and (2) using parallel processing. I have another idea, will try to develop it into an answer, meanwhile could you please share details what are the dimensions, resolution, and buffer size in the real application? Or even post an example of a raster? Thanks

Comment: The rasters I want to apply this on are the MODIS LST products for Bavaria for the years 2003 until 2019:
`dimension(s):
     from  to  offset    delta                       refsys point                    values
x       1 408 4284425  860.124 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon... FALSE                      NULL
y       1 426 5604907 -860.358 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon... FALSE                      NULL` so it's 173808 pixels per year/raster.
I will upload the subset I am trying with now in the main post (96 pixels)

Comment: Thanks! Please see one approach below, you can test it on your rasters, first convert them to `terra` object with two bands (using function `rast` I guess), or reading directly from a file, then modify the buffer size (in the example it's `10`) and elevation threshold (in the example it's `5`).

Comment: P.S. 408x426 is not an extremely big raster, to keep the code simple I'd still try the "loop" approach just in case it does execute in a reasonable period of time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below a solution using `terra`. The code uses `terra::extract` to create two corresponding `list`s:

- The pixel values
- The surrounding buffer values

Subsequently the values are processed pairwise, using `mapply`, with a function similar to the one you suggested.

It's the first time I'm using `terra` but seems like `terra::extract` is much faster than `raster::extract`, therefore this solution may be feasible even for a large raster.

Creating sample data:

```r
library(sf)
library(terra)

r = rast(ncol = ncol(volcano), nrow = nrow(volcano), xmin = 0, xmax = ncol(volcano), ymin = 0, ymax = nrow(volcano))
values(r) = volcano
s = r
s[] = rnorm(ncell(s))
r = c(r, s)
crs(r) = ""
plot(r)
```

[image: input]

Calculating buffers:

```r
pnt = as.points(r, values = FALSE)
pol = buffer(pnt, 10)
```

Extracting raster values from points:

```r
x = extract(r, pnt)
head(x)
```

```
##      ID lyr.1       lyr.1
## [1,]  1   100 -0.03525223
## [2,]  2   100  0.31525467
## [3,]  3   101  0.94054608
## [4,]  4   101  0.37209238
## [5,]  5   101 -0.38388234
## [6,]  6   101 -0.03120593
```

Extracting raster values from buffers:

```r
y = extract(r, pol)
head(y)
```

```
##      ID lyr.1       lyr.1
## [1,]  1   100 -0.03525223
## [2,]  1   100  0.31525467
## [3,]  1   101  0.94054608
## [4,]  1   101  0.37209238
## [5,]  1   101 -0.38388234
## [6,]  1   101 -0.03120593
```

Now, the extracted values can be processed sequentially using `mapply`.
First, we convert the objects to `list`s:

```r
x = as.data.frame(x)
x = split(x, x$ID)
y = as.data.frame(y)
y = split(y, y$ID)
```

Next, we use `mapply` to make the necessary calculation, each time
considering the current focal point value `x` and surrounding buffer
values `y`:

```r
f = function(x, y) {
    d = abs(x[, 2] - y[, 2])  ## differences
    values = y[, 3]  ## values
    mean(values[d < 5], na.rm = TRUE)  ## Mean of subset
}
result = mapply(f, x, y)
```

Finally, putting the results back into the raster template:

```r
u = r[[1]]
values(u) = result
plot(u)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it works perfectly!
I tried it on a bigger subset of the data (roughly 10% of the big raster) with a big buffer (47 km) and it worked rather fast (didn't benchmark it, but I think it's in the 20 minutes or so).
I would have never had the idea of using Terra, and using it like you did :)